# How to reset Pandas DataFrame indices?

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, reset, indices

all,

I have (what should be) a very simple Pandas question.  I'm trying to "refresh" the indices of my DataFrame, df.
I'm trying:

```
df3 = df2.reindex()
df3.head()
```

But this still gives me:

```
        Dose
13539.0 1.0
13539.0 2.0
13539.0 5.0
13539.0 3.0
13539.0 4.0
```

I need to keep the "Dose" column in the same order, but make its indices 0 -> len(Dose).

In other words, **my desired output is:**

```
    Dose
0   1.0
1   2.0
2   5.0
3   3.0
4   4.0
```

Clearly I've pre-processed something to mess this up, but I'd appreciate any insight as to how I can ammend it :-)

Thank you!!

Comment: df3.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

Answer (score 5):

**df3.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)**

When you reset the index, the *old index is added as a column*, and a new sequential index is used. Then you can *use the drop parameter to avoid the old index* being added as a column.

Refer to this Pandas documentation.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html

Answer (score 1):

You might want to lookup the documentation for [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html). In your case:

```
df3.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution does the job...

```
df2 = df2.reset_index()
df2 = df2['Dose']
```